# Wait a few seconds before deleting row

Tags: php, mysql

Could somebody help me figure out how I would remove a row in a table moments after it's been created? Preferably 2 minutes. Here I have a row being inserted into the table; I want this same row to be removed after 2 minutes.

```
$con->query("INSERT INTO Tournament (name,age) VALUES ('$name','$age')");
```

Comment: You could use the MySQL Event Scheduler.

Comment: You could also add an "expiry" column and select rows with an expiry less than whatever your threshold is. Then set up some sort of cron job/scheduled task to clean up expired entries, say once a day.

Comment: I'm completely new to php and mysql which is why I'm asking for someone to do this for me.

Comment: I understand that however I do have quite a bit of knowledge in programming with other programs and from past experience, this doesn't seem too hard to make. The only problem is, I have no idea how to do it which is why i'm asking everyone here :D

Comment: Well Barmar and I gave you a couple of suggestions. Try looking into those and see if you can come up with something that works how you want it to for your program.

Comment: figured it out! thanks for your help